# Why do people pronounce "Naomi" as "Niomi"?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, names, vowels

The [Wikipedia page for "Naomi (given name)"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naomi_%28given_name%29) <s>says</s> once said "pronounced nay-oh-mee" which is how I pronounce my daughter's name, but quite often people pronounce it "nigh-oh-mee" (that is, with a long "i" instead of a long "a" in the first syllable).

Is there a reason why so many people pronounce it in this way?  I live near Boston, in case that's a factor.

---

The [Wiktionary page for *Naomi*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Naomi) gives three pronunciations:

- /neɪˈoʊmi/
- /naɪˈoʊmi/
- /ˈneɪəmi/

Comment: "Nay-oh-mee" is nothing like "Niomi". "Niomi" would be either "Nee-oh-mee" or "Nih-oh-mee".

Comment: @tenfour I'm not sure what you mean, but I hope my question is clear enough.  Please let me know if it isn't, and I'll be happy to edit it.  Thanks.

Comment: Some extended discussion on this [here](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2010/05/naomi.html).

Comment: I'm in the UK, and I'd be quite likely to repeat back *"Hi, Nigh-oh-mee!"* even if you'd just introduced me to your daughter as *Nay-oh-mee*. Probably because I'm a lazy "Estuary English" speaker (Americans, read "Valley-speak"). If I can truncate an awkward triphthong into a fairly easy diphthong I will tend to do this unless Naomi complains.

Comment: I think FumbleFingers has nailed it. In general, we all gravitate towards whatever is easier to roll off the tongue. In fact, our family's "Nigh-oh-me" is usually just "No-me". And her Dad is a scholar of ancient languages.

Comment: @Fumble: that could be an answer. Admittedly, in Estuary English you're more likely to talk about Dive than Nighomee...

Comment: I'd just like to highlight this link from @Callithumpian which is a little hard to read (i.e. technical due to what I assume are IPA spellings) but exactly on topic: http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2010/05/naomi.html

Comment: I am a Naomi of 43 years and have always been called Nigh-oh-mee by most people - All over the U.S., UK, etc. I usually don't notice it anymore, but it still irks me. I just don't understand this strange linguistic phenomenon (which is why I finally googled it tonight!). Even when people read my name, like on my driver's license, they will sometimes say "have a good day NIGH-oh-me." Ergh. It's tempting to move to Germany, or South America, or elsewhere where I've been and had it pronounced "Nah-oh-mee," for some reason that feels acceptable. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) I wish your daughter good luck! She will either become all the stronger for it, or will go by the nickname "Nomi," as some of my Naomi friends have done. On the bright side, I believe it is a known name in Hebrew, Japanese, and several African languages, which is kinda cool.

Comment: Even though my name is Naomi its always been pronounced Nigh-o-me. I don't know why but I personally cringe when I hear it the other way. I guess it's because people used to call me Nay and make horse noises. Also when people see my name on a name tag they read it backwards as "i moan". And that's just disturbing!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think this is a mild [hyperforeignism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperforeignism) that comes from an attempt to pronounce “Naomi” more like the original Hebrew: *nah-oh-mee* [na.o.mi]. The [ao] sequence is uncommon in English—and because there are two separately stressed syllables in this case, they cannot merge into *ow* [aʊ]. Thus an [epenthetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epenthesis) /y/ [j] sound appears, giving *nah-yo-mee* [na.joʊ.mi]. This is just like someone saying “drawring” instead of “drawing”: the transition between a certain pair of vowels is uncommon, so a consonant appears to simplify pronunciation.

The reason you *hear* it as *nye-oh-mee* then becomes clear: an [a] sound followed by a [j] sound approximates the regular English “long I”, which is in fact a [diphthong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong), and not a single vowel. As a similar example, consider the word *diode*, which could be rendered as *dye-ode* [daɪ.oʊd], but also as *dah-yode* [da.joʊd].

So it’s a matter of principle: call your daughter by the name (pronunciation) she was given, but also acknowledge that neither pronunciation is really any more “right” than the other. If someone wants to name their daughter Naomi (or son, whatever, it’s a free country) but pronounce it “squeemdge”, then that’s their problem, and they’ll just have to correct people. Often.

Comment: I've heard at least four pronunciations of "Naomi".  As I've indicated, I say "Nay-oh-mee".  The second most common is "Nye-oh-mee" (really!).  A native Spanish speaker says "Nah-yo-mee" (the epenthetic y sound you suggest).  A native Polish speaker says "Nah-oh-mee" (closest to the original Hebrew, perhaps).  All this said, now that you've brought this to my attention, I'll listen more carefully for "Nye-oh-mee" versus "Nah-yo-mee".

Comment: +1 just for the last sentence (though if we ever meet, I shall certainly say "Hello squeemdge")

Comment: Nobody has a problem saying “They owe me”, so why would they have a problem here?  It’s just sloppiness.

Comment: @tchrist: I don’t understand your comment. My answer claims that the “nigh” pronunciation is epenthesis occurring as a result of trying to follow the original pronunciation. Your example seems…completely unrelated.

Comment: @JonPurdy The question is whether the first syllable’s vowel in *Naomi* is perceived as the same one found in *name*, *Nathan*, or *main*, which is /eɪ/.  To me, it is. In that case, you get a diphthong anyway, and the whole thing is just /neɪ.oʊ.mi/, which might be perceived as /ne.joʊ.mi/, I suppose. If you had <ao> fusing into a diphthong, that should naturally go to /aʊ/, which isn’t what’s happening here.

Comment: @tchrist: The *ao* can’t be reduced to [aʊ] because the “o” is a distinct, stressed syllable—[naʊ.mi] would be wrong, or at least misunderstood as *now me*.

Comment: @tchrist Yes, for me "they owe me" sounds very similar to how I pronounce "Naomi". Thanks.

Comment: Here in the San Francisco Bay Area, /naʊ.mi/ “nowmi” is actually quite common, especially among Asian speakers. For some reason, it doesn't bother my daughter, even though she cringes at /na.joʊ.mi/ “nyomi.”

Answer (score 6):

The name *Naomi* is commonly pronounced *nay-OH-mee* in the United States. But as with all Hebrew/Biblical names, one will find several variations in pronunciation since they are not originally English names. Apparently, *nigh-OH-mee* is also accepted, according to [Behind The Name](http://www.behindthename.com/name/naomi-1). In my view, this is less common, but I do not have an answer for why some people would choose to pronounce it this way. I grew up in church in Nigeria, and we always called it *nah-OH-mee* in Sunday School. If you do some research, you will find that this is closer to the actual Hebrew pronunciation.

Another popular Hebrew/Biblical name is Aaron. In America, these days, it is pronounced almost like the name *Erin*. But some swear by *AY-* for the first syllable. Apparently, *AH-* is closer to the original Hebrew.

As with all names, I would go by the commonly accepted pronunciation or stick with how the owner of the name (or their parents) addresses them[selves].

Comment: My wife is named Naomi, and almost every person she has encountered who pronounced it "nigh-OH-mee" was either Jewish from the Northeast U.S. or from the Southern U.S. Most people she has encountered from Central and South America generally conflate her name with "Noemi".

Comment: The Hebrew pronunciations are nah-OH-mee and a-ha-RON (long o).

Comment: @MonicaCellio: "nah-oh-MEE," technically (the accent is on the last syllable Biblically, and I think also in modern Hebrew).

Comment: @Alex, you're right -- my mistake.

Comment: @AlEverett your comment is very interesting.  I do live in the Northeast U.S. (Boston) and my neighborhood has a significant Jewish population.

Comment: Although our Israeli friends usually call my Naomi just Nomi, or even Omi, accent first syllable, I believe the first vowel is a _kamatz katan_, and would have been Naw-‘oh-mee (glottal stop) if we've reconstructed Early Hebrew pronunciation correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a Naomi and my family pronounce it "Neh-me" or "Naya-me". No one else does though and I've never heard it pronounced this way with any other Naomis! When meeting new people I say "Nay-oh-me". I dislike "Nigh-oh-me" and even more so "Nee-oh-me" which seems to be common here in the UK.